# Принцип DIP из SOLID

Tags: php, solid

Правильно ли я понял принцип DIP из SOLID?
Если класс A имеет зависимость от класса B, то при описании класса А зависимость нужно указать через абстракцию, т.е.:

```
interface BInterface { ... }

class B implements BInterface  { ... }

class A {
    public function __construct(BInterface  $b) { ... }
}
```

Если бы мы указали в зависимости, конкретно класс, вот так:

```
class A {
    public function __construct(B $b) { ... }
}
```

то это было бы нарушение принципа DIP ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы всё верно расписали, ваш второй пример нарушает принцип инверсии зависимостей, т.к. класс `A` полностью зависит от класса `B`, если вы измените в будущем класс `B`, то вам придётся отредактировать и другие классы. А в первом примере вы создали для класса `B` интерфейс `BInterface` и тем самым обеспечили независимость модулей разных уровней. Теперь класс `A` не привязан жёстко к конкретному классу, главное чтобы передаваемый объект в конструкторе реализовывал `BInterface` и, соответственно, принцип DIP не нарушается.

Comment: Спасибо большое! еще такой вопрос:
при использовании DI-контейнеров с автовайрингом (autowiring), работать не будет. (пруф http://php-di.org/doc/autowiring.html#limitations)

Т.к. чтобы зависимость подставлялась автоматически, нужно, чтобы был в зависимости указан конкретный класс.

Получается, что если следовать принципу DIP, то автовайринг 
из DI-контейнеров, работать не будет ? и нужно как обычны указывать зависимости вручную в контейнере.

Я совсем в этом запутался.

Comment: @человекмякоть, конкретно про пакет PHP-DI, ссылку на который вы привели, и его возможности сказать затрудняюсь. Но вообще, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, внедрение зависимости через конструктор требует обязательную зависимость, без которой класс в принципе **не будет** работать. Но вообще это довольно обширная тема и в рамках одного комментария я не смогу вам дать развёрнутый ответ.